# C# WPF Потоки пустой программы

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

Process Explorer показывает 12 Threads в пустой release WPF программе. Почему так много и как их понимать? Где-то читал что WPF создает 2 потока один для программы и один для UI.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы запускали не из под студии случайно?

Comment: @Bulson нет, сделал release и потом запустил exe c файлового проводника windows

Comment: WPF для отрисовки интерфейса использует DirectX в отличие от Windows Forms, в котором рисует GDI. Возможно это связано с этим.

Comment: @Bulson но все же интересно почему такое количество, что и куда, подожду на исчерпывающий ответ

Comment: В любой .NET-программе минимум три потока: основной, поток сборщика мусора, поток финализатора. Насчет WPF не в курсе.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Информацию о некоторых служебных потоках CLR можно прочитать [здесь](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/threading.md). Воспользуемся [Debugging Tools for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/), чтобы проверить это на практике.

Запускаем исследуемое приложение (без отладки), запускаем WinDbg, выбираем File -> Attach to process, выбираем в списке наше приложение. Приостанавливаем выполнение с помощью Ctrl+Break. Теперь мы можем получить стеки вызовов всех потоков с помощью команды [~* k](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/k--kb--kc--kd--kp--kp--kv--display-stack-backtrace-):

```
0:012> ~* k

   0  Id: 2b20.1f0c Suspend: 1 Teb: 01086000 Unfrozen
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 012ff24c 73f6a850 win32u!NtUserGetMessage+0xc
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\WindowsBase\03c76d7ce2fb4e82a604311437d4c78e\WindowsBase.ni.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\WindowsBase\03c76d7ce2fb4e82a604311437d4c78e\WindowsBase.ni.dll
01 012ff288 544d9590 USER32!GetMessageW+0x30
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
02 012ff2d0 544ae046 WindowsBase_ni+0xe9590
03 012ff2ec 544aaa80 WindowsBase_ni+0xbe046
04 012ff328 544a8541 WindowsBase_ni+0xbaa80
05 012ff380 544a816e WindowsBase_ni+0xb8541
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Presentatio5ae0f00f#\1ffa8aee628840413da5d86076124375\PresentationFramework.ni.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Presentatio5ae0f00f#\1ffa8aee628840413da5d86076124375\PresentationFramework.ni.dll
06 012ff38c 51c04eca WindowsBase_ni+0xb816e
07 012ff39c 51c04d60 PresentationFramework_ni+0x2c4eca
08 012ff3bc 51c04b07 PresentationFramework_ni+0x2c4d60
09 012ff3cc 05918004 PresentationFramework_ni+0x2c4b07
0a 012ff3d8 7322ebb6 0x5918004
0b 012ff3e4 73231e10 clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x34
0c 012ff438 73237994 clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x6b
0d 012ff4a8 733a5026 clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x16a
0e 012ff5d4 733a5707 clr!RunMain+0x1ad
0f 012ff848 733a55ed clr!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod+0x124
10 012ffd40 733a58d3 clr!SystemDomain::ExecuteMainMethod+0x631
11 012ffd98 733a5819 clr!ExecuteEXE+0x4c
12 012ffdd8 73375a0c clr!_CorExeMainInternal+0xdc
13 012ffe14 739fd93b clr!_CorExeMain+0x4d
14 012ffe50 73a7e8b9 mscoreei!_CorExeMain+0x10e
15 012ffe64 73a84e18 MSCOREE!ShellShim__CorExeMain+0xa9
16 012ffe6c 73d88484 MSCOREE!_CorExeMain_Exported+0x8
17 012ffe80 774141c8 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
18 012ffec8 77414198 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
19 012ffed8 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

   1  Id: 2b20.3868 Suspend: 1 Teb: 01089000 Unfrozen
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 0150f86c 774016d6 ntdll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+0xc
01 0150fa28 73d88484 ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0x296
02 0150fa3c 774141c8 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
03 0150fa84 77414198 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
04 0150fa94 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

   2  Id: 2b20.9dc Suspend: 1 Teb: 0108c000 Unfrozen
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 0172fcfc 774016d6 ntdll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+0xc
01 0172feb8 73d88484 ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0x296
02 0172fecc 774141c8 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
03 0172ff14 77414198 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
04 0172ff24 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

   3  Id: 2b20.3394 Suspend: 1 Teb: 0108f000 Unfrozen
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 018ffb14 774016d6 ntdll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+0xc
01 018ffcd0 73d88484 ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0x296
02 018ffce4 774141c8 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
03 018ffd2c 77414198 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
04 018ffd3c 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

   4  Id: 2b20.1610 Suspend: 1 Teb: 01092000 Unfrozen
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 01aef830 774016d6 ntdll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+0xc
01 01aef9ec 73d88484 ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0x296
02 01aefa00 774141c8 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
03 01aefa48 77414198 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
04 01aefa58 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

   5  Id: 2b20.3bac Suspend: 1 Teb: 01095000 Unfrozen
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 0338fc94 75fa5a13 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
01 0338fe28 73374a4b KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x133
02 0338fe94 733749a0 clr!DebuggerRCThread::MainLoop+0x99
03 0338fec4 733748cd clr!DebuggerRCThread::ThreadProc+0xd0
04 0338fef4 73d88484 clr!DebuggerRCThread::ThreadProcStatic+0xc4
05 0338ff08 774141c8 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
06 0338ff50 77414198 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
07 0338ff60 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

   6  Id: 2b20.334c Suspend: 1 Teb: 01098000 Unfrozen
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 055af738 75fa5a13 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
01 055af8cc 733c16eb KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x133
02 055af8fc 733b039e clr!FinalizerThread::WaitForFinalizerEvent+0x8a
03 055af92c 7323a029 clr!FinalizerThread::FinalizerThreadWorker+0x5f
04 055af940 7323a093 clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+0x71
05 055af9e4 7323a160 clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+0x7e
06 055afa40 733a4e38 clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+0x5b
07 055afa68 733a4ea5 clr!ManagedThreadBase::FinalizerBase+0x33
08 055afaa4 732aed61 clr!FinalizerThread::FinalizerThreadStart+0xd9
09 055afb48 73d88484 clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x55
0a 055afb5c 774141c8 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
0b 055afba4 77414198 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
0c 055afbb4 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

   7  Id: 2b20.377c Suspend: 1 Teb: 0109b000 Unfrozen
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 05cbfa10 774016d6 ntdll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+0xc
01 05cbfbcc 73d88484 ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0x296
02 05cbfbe0 774141c8 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
03 05cbfc28 77414198 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
04 05cbfc38 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

   8  Id: 2b20.3588 Suspend: 1 Teb: 0109e000 Unfrozen
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 05dffab8 774016d6 ntdll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+0xc
01 05dffc74 73d88484 ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0x296
02 05dffc88 774141c8 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
03 05dffcd0 77414198 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
04 05dffce0 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

   9  Id: 2b20.35ec Suspend: 1 Teb: 010a1000 Unfrozen
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 05f3f54c 75fa5a13 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
01 05f3f6e0 76f8d24e KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x133
02 05f3f81c 76fee2ae combase!WaitCoalesced+0xb5 [onecore\com\published\comutils\coalescedwait.cxx @ 72] 
03 05f3f84c 76f8ae34 combase!CROIDTable::WorkerThreadLoop+0x4e [onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\refcache.cxx @ 1650] 
04 05f3f878 76f8802f combase!CRpcThread::WorkerLoop+0x11f [onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\threads.cxx @ 269] 
05 05f3f888 73d88484 combase!CRpcThreadCache::RpcWorkerThreadEntry+0x1f [onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\threads.cxx @ 76] 
06 05f3f89c 774141c8 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
07 05f3f8e4 77414198 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
08 05f3f8f4 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

  10  Id: 2b20.20e8 Suspend: 1 Teb: 010a4000 Unfrozen
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 061ffab4 75f94699 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc
01 061ffb28 75f945f2 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x99
02 061ffb3c 515f10b7 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
03 061ffb68 515f33b8 wpfgfx_v0400!CPartitionManager::GetWork+0x165
04 061ffb80 5164088f wpfgfx_v0400!CPartitionThread::Run+0x18
05 061ffba8 73d88484 wpfgfx_v0400!CPartitionThread::ThreadMain+0x2f
06 061ffbbc 774141c8 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
07 061ffc04 77414198 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
08 061ffc14 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

  11  Id: 2b20.3268 Suspend: 1 Teb: 010a7000 Unfrozen
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 092df710 774016d6 ntdll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+0xc
01 092df8cc 73d88484 ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0x296
02 092df8e0 774141c8 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
03 092df928 77414198 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
04 092df938 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

# 12  Id: 2b20.4e8 Suspend: 1 Teb: 010ad000 Unfrozen
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 0f91fd58 77454369 ntdll!DbgBreakPoint
01 0f91fd88 73d88484 ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin+0x39
02 0f91fd9c 774141c8 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
03 0f91fde4 77414198 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
04 0f91fdf4 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

Разбираем результат.

**Поток 0.** По наличию в стеке `USER32!GetMessageW`, легко понять, что это поток с циклом обработки сообщений (именно на нем запускается большая часть вашего кода, например, обработчики событий и делегаты DispatcherTimer).

**Потоки 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 11.**  По наличию в стеке `ntdll!TppWorkerThread` видно, что это потоки из [Thread Pool](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2233328&seqNum=6) (не пула CLR, а нативного пула Windows). Хороший вопрос, почему 7 потоков Thread Pool автоматически создаются в любом приложении, даже когда мы этого не заказывали (не только в WPF, но и в абсолютно пустом консольном приложении на С++!). Разгадка в том, что [в Windows 10 Thread Pool используется для распараллеливания загрузки DLL](https://threatvector.cylance.com/en_us/home/windows-10-parallel-loading-breakdown.html), с целью ускорения запуска процессов на машинах с несколькими процессорными ядрами.

**Поток 5.** CLR Debugger Thread - служебный поток, обеспечивающий работу отладчиков управляемого кода.

**Поток 6.** CLR Finalizer Thread - служебный поток, на котором GC запускает финализаторы.

**Поток 9.** Стек вызовов мало что дает, но методом исключения, получается это GC Thread. Отсутствие в стеке каких-либо функций CLR, вероятно, объясняется тем, что сборщик мусора еще не был инициализирован на тот момент.

**Поток 10.** `wpfgfx_v0400` - это неуправляемая библиотека, которую WPF использует для рендеринга графики. Так как WPF использует DirectX, для рендеринга нужен отдельный поток, чтобы делать это максимально быстро независимо от загруженности очереди сообщений.

**Поток 12.** Символ `ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin` говорит о том, что это поток, порожденный самим отладчиком (реализация отладки в Windows требует инжектирования в отлаживаемый процесс специального потока). Иными словами, этот поток не имеет отношения к приложению.

---

Всего 13 потоков, из них один привнесен отладчиком - итого 12 потоков собственно приложения. Вроде все удалось опознать. Как видно, непосредственное отношение к WPF действительно имеют только два потока (0 и 10).